# StructureMap and auto registering

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, structuremap

I have 3 projects:

`Core` (contains domain models and interfaces for repositories, services, etc.)
`Repository` (concrete implementation of repositories)
`Web` (MVC 4 project).

Inside ObjectFactory.Initialize I have something like this:

```
For<IFooRepository>().Use<FooRepository>();
For<IBooRepository>().Use<BooRepository>();
...
```

Let's say I have 50 repositories, does it mean that I have to write 50 lines of code (one for each concrete implementation)? Can `StructureMap` somehow figure out that `FooRepository` implements `IFooRepositor` interface and instantiate that class when `IFooRepository` interface is requested?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StructureMap does allow you to do this programmatically by scanning an assembly and applying a convention to connect interfaces to types. Here is an example:

```
public class RepositoryRegistry : StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry
{
    public RepositoryRegistry()
    {
        Scan(s =>
        {
            s.AssemblyContainingType<ApplicationRepository>();
            s.Convention<TypeNamingConvention>();
        });
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class TypeNamingConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        Type interfaceType = type.GetInterfaces()
            .ToList()
            .Where(t => t.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("i" + type.Name.ToLowerInvariant()))
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (interfaceType != null)
        {
            registry.AddType(interfaceType, type);
        }
    }
}
```

and you call the registry at initialization time like this:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.Scan(s =>
{
 s.TheCallingAssembly();
 s.LookForRegistries();
}));
```

This convention just assumes the standard that your type matches the interface + "I". Hopefully that gives you enough to go on.

Comment: This is correct, but you do not need to create your own convention class in this case. Use WithDefaultConvention in your Scan clause.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaFlanagan, I didn't know you could do that!